# Store xrandr settings in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors

How can I permanently store my xrandr settings in Ubuntu 12.04? I use xrandr to change the setting of my primary monitor but I don't want to do it again and again after I reboot my system.

Answer (score 0):

Just solved it by editing /home/.config/monitors.xml such that the desired screen is primary in all configs.